# PySpark: java.io.EOFException

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

We started receiving this generic today-

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:  java.io.EOFException

Saw some articles talking about this being from big files, missing libraries, or memory constraints.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/pyspark-java-io-eofexception

[PySpark throws java.io.EOFException when reading big files with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086923/pyspark-throws-java-io-eofexception-when-reading-big-files-with-boto3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For us it ended up being an empty .seq file that was written by one of our ETL tools.  Removing that invalid file resolved the issue for us.