# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. While executing simple .map()

Tags: pyspark

I am new to pySpark & trying a simple pySpark code, like reading a file and using .map(), but getting Py4JJavaError while executing

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

config = SparkConf().setAppName("Reading file")  # App name can be anything
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=config)
rdd = sc.textFile("../files/number_file.txt")

rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(","))
print(rdd2.collect())
```

and the text file is

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

Error I am getting is:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:210)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:385)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 32 more
```

I am using python 3.12
jdk 17
spark 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes setting up spark can be the issue.  Do add the entire error if you can.

Your code looks okay and works in an openjdk17 + spark3.5.0 + scala2.13 environment.

I noticed that your csv file doesn't end in a comma before the newline.  In the colab notebook I tried reading in your text file with the comma added between: 10,11 20,21 30,31 40,41. I also tried reading the original file presented in the question.  Both ways work; however, if you're reading in a csv file, I'm a fan of using the functions that read in that file.

The collab notebook demonstrating your code works can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18GuYdCQeJrP65-rm2i4udJJjsDQNcsYf?usp=sharing)

Here's my setup and how I would've created a data frame differently:

The setup I used in a notebook in google collab:

```
# download JVM
!apt-get install openjdk-17-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
# download spark+hadoop+scala
!wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.5.0/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13.tgz
# unpack
!tar -xf spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13.tgz
# setup paths
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = '/content/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13'
# Install library for finding Spark
!pip install -q findspark
# Import the libary
import findspark
# Initiate findspark
findspark.init()
# Check the location for Spark
findspark.find()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("stackoverflow example") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
```

Your code worked fine Here's my implementation (I tried a couple of different ways [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18GuYdCQeJrP65-rm2i4udJJjsDQNcsYf?usp=sharing) ):

```
orig_text = """1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40
41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50
"""
with open("number_file_orig.txt", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write(f"{orig_text}")
rdd_orig = sc.textFile("number_file_orig.txt")

rdd2_orig = rdd_orig.map(lambda x: x.split(","))
print(rdd2_orig.collect())

# output [['1', ' 2', ' 3', ' 4', ' 5', ' 6', ' 7', ' 8', ' 9', ' 10'], ['11', ' 12', ' 13', ' 14', ' 15', ' 16', ' 17', ' 18', ' 19', ' 20'], ['21', ' 22', ' 23', ' 24', ' 25', ' 26', ' 27', ' 28', ' 29', ' 30'], ['31', ' 32', ' 33', ' 34', ' 35', ' 36', ' 37', ' 38', ' 39', ' 40'], ['41', ' 42', ' 43', ' 44', ' 45', ' 46', ' 47', ' 48', ' 49', ' 50']]
```

I was thinking you probably wanted to use a pyspark dataframe at some point, so I would've done something like this:

```
 numbers_df = spark.read.csv('../files/number_file.txt', sep=',',
                         inferSchema=True, header=False)
 numbers_df.show()
```

Because there is no schema defined the output from numbers_df.show() is:

```
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|_c0| _c1| _c2| _c3| _c4| _c5| _c6| _c7| _c8| _c9|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1| 2.0| 3.0| 4.0| 5.0| 6.0| 7.0| 8.0| 9.0|10.0|
| 11|12.0|13.0|14.0|15.0|16.0|17.0|18.0|19.0|20.0|
| 21|22.0|23.0|24.0|25.0|26.0|27.0|28.0|29.0|30.0|
| 31|32.0|33.0|34.0|35.0|36.0|37.0|38.0|39.0|40.0|
| 41|42.0|43.0|44.0|45.0|46.0|47.0|48.0|49.0|50.0|
+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Error I am getting is:
```console
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:210)
        at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:385)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:774)
        ... 32 more
```

Comment: I don't think your code is at fault here, as demonstrated by the colab notebook.  When you have a Java EOFException, it ndicates the datastream is encountering an EOF unexpectedly (and remember your file is small.. so spark must be running out of memory when reading).  The collab notebook that I ran had 12GB Ram and, because of the nature of my notebook,  a spark instance is created and destroyed whenever I needed to test your code.

Comment: I think you are running out of memory: some further research on the topic turned up a similar issue but resolved after adding more memory or changing configuration: (Solution: it's an installation issue or change memory config ) --> 
 https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40130/pyspark-java-io-eofexception/92690#92690?newreg=b79477fd8d134636a7e6648420d11969    (Solution: unpersist RDDs + manage memory better) --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086923/pyspark-throws-java-io-eofexception-when-reading-big-files-with-boto3

Comment: Also, thank you for adding the full error!  It helped establish potential root cause.  Clearly your code is okay, but your spark cluster and its memory usage are likely the culprit here.